# Keras: What is the difference between layers.Input and layers.InputLayer?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

When should I use `Input` and when should I use `InputLayer`? In the [source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py) there is a description, but I am not sure what it means.

InputLayer:

> Layer to be used as an entry point into a graph.
>       It can either wrap an existing tensor (pass an `input_tensor` argument)
>       or create its a placeholder tensor (pass arguments `input_shape`
>       or `batch_input_shape` as well as `dtype`).

Input:

> `Input()` is used to instantiate a Keras tensor.
>       A Keras tensor is a tensor object from the underlying backend
>       (Theano or TensorFlow), which we augment with certain
>       attributes that allow us to build a Keras model
>       just by knowing the inputs and outputs of the model.

Comment: I have never user an InputLayer. I always use `Input()` to generate the input tensor. I've also never seen an example using `InputLayer`.

Comment: I'm not sure who's right about it (if `InputLayer` should be used or not), but I'm sure it's part of TF's own version hell. It is compounded with problems coming from mixing `tf.keras` with `keras.*` (using Tensorflow backend).

Answer (score 2):

I think `InputLayer` has been deprecated together with the Graph models. I would suggest you use Input, as all the examples on the Keras documentations show.

Comment: Where did you read that `InputLayer` is deprecated? TensorFlow 2 still supports it: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/InputLayer.

Comment: You are right, I can't find any reference to it. I honestly don't remember where I got that from. And this is why one should always provide sources to such statements...Anyways, these two threads seem to provide a good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147019/keras-difference-of-inputlayer-and-input and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217973/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-an-inputlayer-or-an-input-in-a-keras-model-with

Answer (score 0):

`InputLayer` is a callable, just like other keras layers, while `Input` is not callable, it is simply a Tensor object.

You can use `InputLayer` when you need to connect it like layers to the following layers:

```
inp = keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(32,))(prev_layer)
```

and following is the usage of `Input` layer:

```
x = Input(shape=(32,))
y = Dense(16, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(x, y)
```