# What is the advantage of using an InputLayer (or an Input) in a Keras model with Tensorflow tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

A Keras model can used as a Tensorflow function on a Tensor, through the functional API, as described [here](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html#calling-keras-layers-on-tensorflow-tensors%20here).

So we can do:

```
from keras.layers import InputLayer

a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))

model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_tensor=a, input_shape=(None, 784)))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

output = model.output
```

Which is a tensor:

```
<tf.Tensor 'dense_24/Softmax:0' shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32>
```

But, this also works without any `InputLayer`:

```
a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

output = model(a)
```

works, and `output` has the same shape as before:

```
<tf.Tensor 'sequential_9/dense_22/Softmax:0' shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32>
```

I assume the first form permits:

- to explicitely attach the `inputs` and `outputs` as attributes of the model (of the same names), so we can reuse them elsewhere. For example with other TF ops.
- to transform the tensors given as inputs into Keras inputs, with additional metadata (such as `_keras_history` as stated in [the source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py#L1369-L1372)).

But this is not something we cannot do with the second form, so, is there a special usage of the `InputLayer` (and `Input` a fortiori) (except for multiple inputs)?
Moreover, the `InputLayer` is tricky because it's using `input_shape` differently from other keras layers: we specify the batch size (`None` here), which is not usually the case...

Answer (score 30):

It would seem that `InputLayer` has some uses:

- First, it allows you to give pure tensorflow tensors as is, without specifying their shape. E.g. you could have written

  ```
    model.add(InputLayer(input_tensor=a))
  ```

  This is nice for several obvious reasons, among others less duplication.
- Second, they allow you to write non-sequential networks with a single input, e.g.

  ```
        input
         / \
        /   \
       /     \
    conv1   conv2
      |       |
  ```

  Without `InputLayer` you would need to explicitly feed `conv1` and `conv2` the same tensor, or create an arbitrary identity layer on top of the model. Neither is quite pleasing.
- Finally, they remove the arbitrary distinction between "layers that are also inputs" and "normal layers". If you use `InputLayer` you can write code where there is a clear distinction between what layer is the input and what layer does something. This improves code readability and makes refactoring much easier. For example, replacing the first layer becomes just as easy as replacing any other layer, you don't need to think about `input_shape`.