# proper input shape for video classification ,use folder picture

Tags: python, deep-learning

Here are the problem issues.I have multiples folders ,each folder have 37 photos ,one photos have 126 keypoints,how can I reshape the input shape since I got error saying
`ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 5) are incompatible`

[input shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrkri.png)

the model structe if needed

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import  Sequential
from  tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM,Dense
from  tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import  tensorflow as tf


log_dir = os.path.join('logs')
callback = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(64,input_shape=(37,126,),return_sequences=True,activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(128,return_sequences=True,activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(64,return_sequences=False,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(class_label.shape[0],activation='softmax'))


model.summary()
```

I want to know where i should check ,thank you for all the answer

Comment: Have you tried adding an input layer to the model? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input

Comment: @NamNguyenHoang Isn't the LSTM cell `input_shape `enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my attempt at replicating your code, assuming 5 output classes (with an extra [Input](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input) layer for my sanity: [What is the advantage of using an InputLayer (or an Input) in a Keras model with Tensorflow tensors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217973/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-an-inputlayer-or-an-input-in-a-keras-model-with)):

```
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import tensorflow as tf

#log_dir = os.path.join('logs')
#callback = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape = (37, 126,)))
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape = (37, 126,), return_sequences = True, activation = 'relu', name = 'lstm1'))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences = True, activation = 'relu', name = 'lstm2'))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences = False, activation = 'relu', name = 'lstm3'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu', name = 'd1'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu', name = 'd2'))

model.add(Dense(5, activation = 'softmax', name = 'out'))

model.summary()
```

The result is as shown below:

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm1 (LSTM)                (None, 37, 64)            48896     
                                                                 
 lstm2 (LSTM)                (None, 37, 128)           98816     
                                                                 
 lstm3 (LSTM)                (None, 64)                49408     
                                                                 
 d1 (Dense)                  (None, 64)                4160      
                                                                 
 d2 (Dense)                  (None, 32)                2080      
                                                                 
 out (Dense)                 (None, 5)                528       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 203,888
Trainable params: 203,888
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Perhaps the problem is not with your input shape, but output? If your image is correct, the model predicts images into ? classes, but only validate to a single class, and thus can not be compared directly. Consider padding the ground truth and prediction result to be the same size first.

[image: Your image, assuming y to be the label list]