# Keras: difference of InputLayer and Input

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I made a model using Keras with Tensorflow.  I use `Inputlayer` with these lines of code:

```
img1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, img_width, img_heigh, img_ch))
first_input = InputLayer(input_tensor=img1, input_shape=(img_width, img_heigh, img_ch)) 
first_dense = Conv2D(16, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='1st_conv1')(first_input)
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: Layer 1st_conv1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.engine.topology.InputLayer'>. Full input: [<keras.engine.topology.InputLayer object at 0x00000000112170F0>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

When I use `Input` like this, it works fine:

```
first_input = Input(tensor=img1, shape=(224, 224, 3), name='1st_input')
first_dense = Conv2D(16, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='1st_conv1')(first_input)
```

What is the difference between `Inputlayer` and `Input`?

Answer (score 28):

- `InputLayer` is a layer.
- `Input` is a tensor.

You can only call layers passing tensors to them.

**The idea is:**

```
outputTensor = SomeLayer(inputTensor)
```

So, only `Input` can be passed because it's a tensor.

Honestly, I have no idea about the reason for the existence of `InputLayer`. Maybe it's supposed to be used internally. I never used it, and it seems I'll never need it.

Comment: Yet, when creating an Input in Keras and serialize the model to json, the Input gets converted to an InputLayer... so I guess it is not just internal. Not sure why though.

Comment: I also didn't know what it was for, but my colleague said it can be used to specify input shape without the need to `.compile()` the model (in case of `Sequential()` anyway).

Comment: There is absolutely no relation with compile. Compile is for adding the optimizer, metrics and loss to the graph. You will need to compile for training, you will not need to compile for other things.

Answer (score 9):

According to tensorflow website, "It is generally recommend to use the functional layer API via Input, (which creates an InputLayer) without directly using InputLayer." 
Know more at this page [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/InputLayer)

Answer (score 7):

Input: Used for creating a functional model

```
inp=tf.keras.Input(shape=[?,?,?])
x=layers.Conv2D(.....)(inp)
```

Input Layer: used for creating a sequential model

```
x=tf.keras.Sequential()
x.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(shape=[?,?,?]))
```

And the other difference is that

> When using InputLayer with the Keras Sequential model, it can be skipped by moving the input_shape parameter to the first layer after the InputLayer.

That is in sequential model you can skip the InputLayer and specify the shape directly in the first layer.
i.e From this

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(4,)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(8)])
```

To this

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape=(4,))])
```

Answer (score 0):

To define it in simple words:

`keras.layers.Input` is used to instantiate a Keras Tensor. In this case, your data is probably not a tf tensor, maybe an `np` array.

On the other hand, `keras.layers.InputLayer` is a layer where your data is already defined as one of the tf tensor types, i.e., can be a ragged tensor or constant or other types.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing on what has already been said, I tested and they don't seem equivalent (a similar layout doesn't generate the exact same results). So might be better to just stay with input_shape as recommended.

[image: Defining models]

[image: Different results]