# Difference between keras.layers.InputLayer and keras.Input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Could someone explain what the advantage of using `keras.layers.InputLayer` over the `keras.Input` tensor is? I understand that one is a tensor, the other is a layer object. However my question is more from a practical point of view as in why one would define the input in a certain way when using the functional API.

Thanks!

Comment: It is generally recommend to use the functional layer API via `Input`, (which creates an `InputLayer`) without directly using `InputLayer`. When using `InputLayer` with Keras Sequential model, it can be skipped by moving the `input_shape` parameter to the first layer after the `InputLayer`. For more details you can refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/InputLayer) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147019/keras-difference-of-inputlayer-and-input). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of community providing solution here

It is generally recommend to use the functional layer API via `Input`, (which creates an `InputLayer`) without directly using `InputLayer`. When using `InputLayer` with Keras Sequential model, it can be skipped by moving the `input_shape` parameter to the first layer after the `InputLayer`. For more details you can refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/InputLayer) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147019/keras-difference-of-inputlayer-and-input).